# How remove first word in Array

Tags: php

I have list names in array, example:

```
$list = array(
   'Rodrigo Vieira Eufrasio da Silva',
   'Alexandre Espolaor',
   'Anne Graciano Espolaor',
   'Tatiana monteiro Cassapula'
);
```

How remove first name of the list.
it's possible?

Comment: Hint: how would you do it if you only had one name to do it on, instead of an array of names?

Comment: Sidenote, first names can have spaces... There's no reliable way to determine what is a first vs middle vs last name given a space-separated list of names.

Comment: Your question appears ambiguous - do you want to remove the first name from each element, "Rodrigo ", "Alexandre ", "Anne " etc or do you want to remove the first element "Rodrigo Vieira Eufrasio da Silva" from the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

```
array_shift($list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible)

```
array_walk($list,function(&$row){
    $row = preg_replace('/^\w+\W+/','',$row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I was not clear, below I will leave I will leave what I need:

1-) I have a CSV file with a column called Students, which contains 426 full names of launches

2-) I need to read this file and store this data in the Array (I already did that)

3-) I need to process this data to create a new CSV file with the following columns.

Firts Name, Last Name, Email, password,

4-) I need to take this Array and take only the first name and put it in the First Name column

5-) Take all surnames in the Array and put in Last Name

6-) Take the Array, convert all data to lowercase, remove all blank spaces, and remove all accents and add the following extension @ mydomain.com

7-) Password is the same for all passw12345

8-) Export this data to CSV for item 3 with the name users.csv